# Getting "Error loading object from InputStream" exception during call JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate pdf via button but my problem is this method
`JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream,servletOutputStream, new HashMap<Object, Object>(), resultSetDataSource);`

it is not supporting Hashmap it gives following error

```
The method runReportToPdfStream(InputStream, OutputStream, Map<String,Object>, Connection) in the type JasperRunManager is 
 not applicable for the arguments (InputStream, ServletOutputStream, HashMap<Object,Object>, JRResultSetDataSource)
```

it Supports String parameter like `Hashmap<String,Object>` while generating pdf it gives following error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from InputStream
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:219)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:632)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:428)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(JasperRunManager.java:849)
    at com.p41.jasper.Jasper.doPost(Jasper.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.p41.setting.FacesFilter.doFilter(FacesFilter.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C3F786D
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:53)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:214)
```

Servlet

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRResultSetDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager;

public class Jasper extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection connection;
        Statement statement;
        ResultSet resultSet;
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String si = request.getParameter("input");

        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] bytes = null;

        InputStream reportStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/HR/Jasp.jasper");
        System.out.println("Print" + si);
        try {
            System.out.println("Second print" + si);

            String query = "SELECT  Where Empno = '" + si + "' ";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemedb?user=root&password=root");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet);

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");

            servletOutputStream.flush();
            servletOutputStream.close();

            System.out.println("print" + reportStream);
            System.out.println("print" + servletOutputStream);
            System.out.println("print" + resultSetDataSource);
            JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, new HashMap<Object, Object>(), resultSetDataSource);

            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            servletOutputStream.flush();
            servletOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getOutputStream().print(stringWriter.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the remaining code

Comment: here is the Servlet code

Comment: wht did u get for System.out.println("print" + reportStream);

Comment: printjava.io.ByteArrayInputStream@39fcd9f5 -Thanks in advance

Comment: Paste this..................URL url = getClass().getResource("WEB-INF/HR/Jasp.jasper");
..........String path = url.getPath();............
......... System.out.println("Path--->"+path );...........and show the output what it prints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is I Removed  Run Report pdf stream and used method as exportReport to pdf Stream

```
JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream,servletOutputStream, new HashMap<Object, Object>(), resultSetDataSource);
```

Coding:-

```
 InputStream reportStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/HR/Jasp.jrxml");


ByteArrayOutputStream baos =new ByteArrayOutputStream();
response.setContentType("application/pdf");

JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);

JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
JRResultSetDataSource jasperReports = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap(), jasperReports);


net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print,baos);
response.setContentLength(baos.size());
ServletOutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(out1);
out1.flush();
rs.close();
st.close();
conn.close();
```